# Выбор из Sqlite по дате

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, sqlite3

Имеется БД Sqlite3 с полем даты в формате TEXT. Как выбрать записи, попадающие в интервал дат?

Интервал задается значениями DateEdit PyQT5. Если я эти значения преобразую в строку, то выборка идет по первому значению числа. Т.е. если задан интервал 01.12.2021-15.12.2021, то в выборку попадут все даты, число которых <= 15 невзирая на месяц и год. Если значения пользовательских дат оставляю как есть не преобразуя в string, то понятно, что падает с ошибкой.
Сами данные в базе и DateEdit одинаковы формата dd.MM.yyyy

Пример:

```
dt1 = self.dtStart.date().toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
dt2 = self.dtEnd.date().toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
'SELECT dateRec, nameKli FROM main WHERE dateRec BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY dateRec', (dt1, dt2))
```

Comment: SQLite поддерживает исключительно ISO 8601 форматы даты. Так что форматировать дату надо строго в формат `YYYY-MM-DD` либо `YYYYMMDD`. Да и хранить в таком же формате. См. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Akina, спасибо. Я уже потом докумекал, что так надо хранить и затем выводить в нужном виде. А сейчас много надо менять в коде. Все заточено на сохранение в dd.mm.yyyy Придется для фильтрации приводить к "простому" виду и использовать что-то вроде LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

В данном конкретном случае, вероятно, поможет фильтрация в коде python
Приблизительно так:

```py
from sqlite3 import connect
from datetime import datetime

conn = connect('mydb.sqlite')

cur = conn.cursor()

date_pattern = "%d.%m.%Y"


l_bound = datetime(2021, 12, 1)
u_bound = datetime(2021, 12, 15)

cur.execute(
    "SELECT dateRec, nameKli FROM main ORDER BY dateRec"
)

def in_range(val: tuple):
    d, _ = val
    return l_bound <= datetime.strptime(d, date_pattern) <= u_bound


dataset = [*filter(in_range, cur.fetchall())]
```

> Не стал пытаться манипулировать не понятными мне `date().toString("dd.MM.yyyy")` и т.д. из неизвестного мне класса.

> Не могу не согласиться с тем, что в этом случае каждый раз придется таскать полный набор записей из таблицы, но...

Comment: Спасибо всем большое. Жаль пока не могу плюсы ставить. Пришлось все-таки поправить формат хранения в sqlite на yyyyMMdd и затем просто изменить вывод в TreeWidget.